# How many cores is optimal in parallel processing?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, doparallel

Say I have an 8 core CPU. Using `doParallel` in R, when I register `makeCluster(x)`, what is the ideal number of cores, `x`, to use?

Is it as many cores as possible? Or would using 7 cores be slower than using 6 cores? Are there any rules around this?

Comment: It depends on the workload, and whether it is CPU bound or IO bound.  Do some benchmarks and find out

Comment: don't know if you are using `library(caret)` but this has a nice illustration of your question for model training, https://topepo.github.io/caret/parallel-processing.html It really depends on the type of work you are doing, but there will always be diminishing returns

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments, the optimal amount of cores depends on the task at hand, but you can find out yourself. Initialize 7 different clusters and benchmark the results. I wouldnt go with all 8 cores, so 7 should be maximum in your case.

Here's a small "silly" template where parallelization doesnt make sense as the simple sapply version is a lot faster because the overhead sent to the cores drastically reduces performance.

Anyway, insert the code you want to optimize, play around and find the perfect setting ;)

```
require(parallel)
cl2 = makeCluster(2)
cl3 = makeCluster(3)
cl4 = makeCluster(4)
cl5 = makeCluster(5)
cl6 = makeCluster(6)
cl7 = makeCluster(7)

library(microbenchmark)
mc <- microbenchmark(times = 100,
                     noPa = {
                       res = sapply(mtcars, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
                     },
                     cor2 = {
                       res = parSapply(cl2, mtcars, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
                     },
                     cor3 = {
                       res = parSapply(cl3, mtcars, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
                     },
                     cor4 = {
                       res = parSapply(cl4, mtcars, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
                     },
                     cor5 = {
                       res = parSapply(cl5, mtcars, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
                     },
                     cor6 = {
                       res = parSapply(cl6, mtcars, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
                     },
                     cor7 = {
                       res = parSapply(cl7, mtcars, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
                     }
); mc

stopCluster(cl2);stopCluster(cl3);stopCluster(cl4);
stopCluster(cl5);stopCluster(cl6);stopCluster(cl7)
```

> ```
> Unit: microseconds
>  expr      min        lq       mean   median        uq       max neval
>  noPa   77.370   94.4365   97.52549   97.281  101.5475   131.983   100
>  cor2  713.388  804.1260  947.56529  836.553  887.4680  7178.812   100
>  cor3  840.250  941.2275 1071.55460  967.681 1027.4145  5343.576   100
>  cor4  877.797 1046.7570 1194.51996 1077.761 1132.3745  7028.057   100
>  cor5 1032.535 1139.2015 1303.64424 1190.686 1241.3170  8148.199   100
>  cor6 1141.761 1222.5430 1438.18655 1261.797 1339.1655 10589.302   100
>  cor7 1269.192 1345.4240 1586.03513 1399.468 1487.3615 10547.204   100
> ```

And here an example where it would make sense to parallelize. Based on the results 7 cores would be the fastest solution. If you run it on your own machine and want to do other stuff next to it, I would go with 4 cores as the timings are comparable and the machine is not working at max capacity.

```
library(lme4)
f <- function(i) {
  lmer(Petal.Width ~ . - Species + (1 | Species), data = iris)
}

library(microbenchmark)
mc <- microbenchmark(times = 3,
                     noPa = {
                       res = sapply(1:100, f)
                     },
                     cor2 = {
                       res = parSapply(cl2, 1:100, f)
                     },
                     cor3 = {
                       res = parSapply(cl3, 1:100, f)
                     },
                     cor4 = {
                       res = parSapply(cl4, 1:100, f)
                     },
                     cor5 = {
                       res = parSapply(cl5, 1:100, f)
                     },
                     cor6 = {
                       res = parSapply(cl6, 1:100, f)
                     },
                     cor7 = {
                       res = parSapply(cl7, 1:100, f)
                     }
); mc
```

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>  expr       min        lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
>  noPa 1925.2889 1964.9473 2169.9294 2004.6057 2292.250 2579.894     3
>  cor2 1501.8176 1591.5596 1722.1834 1681.3015 1832.366 1983.431     3
>  cor3 1097.4251 1188.6271 1345.1643 1279.8291 1469.034 1658.239     3
>  cor4  956.9829 1007.6607 1302.2984 1058.3384 1474.956 1891.574     3
>  cor5 1027.5877 1872.3501 2379.9384 2717.1125 3056.114 3395.115     3
>  cor6 1001.2572 1048.8277 1217.5999 1096.3983 1325.771 1555.144     3
>  cor7  815.2055  905.7948  945.7555  996.3841 1011.030 1025.677     3
> ```

Comment: It's weird. I am training a classifier on 10 classes on a 12 core machine. If I use X > 3 cores I get about 25 seconds of compute time. Increasing cores and compute time stays the same. Watching memory with htop and memory is under 16 GB on 16GB system. 

I think this is because matrix computations are done in parallel anyway, watching htop, I see some parallel action across all the cores. At least I hope that's why